# What information API is out there for video game data using thegamesdb for Android Application?

Tags: android

I want to create a small application in android that just lists upcoming games with their release dates. Ideally this will provide a thumbnail of sorts that when clicked will take the user to that games in android. If application is installed then linked otherwise connect with store for install that game. I want to use thegamesdb.net, I have to sample code.
I am getting game list and details but I want to play that games which is in games list.

please help me How can I achieved it in Android. 
reference link is http://thegamesdb.net/

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Use an API for some website, or launch a game, or look in the Play Store, or what?

Comment: @Shade I want to implement thegamesdb api in android.

Comment: But, but.. that's a whole application! Do you expect us to write the WHOLE APP and post it as an answer here?